# Async await on component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

This is my `componentDidMount` method. I want to set the state of the current user and then call the function when that user is set. How can I do this?

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({user: user})
      }
    });
    this.props.retrieveMatches(this.state.user.uid)
  }
```

I've tried using async/await but im not using it correctly here:

```
  async componentDidMount = () => {
    await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({user: user})
      }
    });
    this.props.retrieveMatches(this.state.user.uid)
  }
```

basically I want to await for lines 2-6 before calling the props function on line 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `.setState()`'s callback function:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({user: user}, () => { 
        this.props.retrieveMatches(this.state.user.uid); 
      })
    }
  });
}
```

greetings

Answer (score 2):

I understand the confusion but that line uses callbacks and not Promises so you're not supposed to use async/await

it should be:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({user: user}, () => { this.props.retrieveMatches(this.state.user.uid); })
    }
  });
}
```

You can use async/await to replace promises then and catch calls

This

```
promise.then((result) => {...}).catch((error) => {});
```

would become

```
try {
  const result = await promise();
} catch (error) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't make a react lifecycle method async.

do an async await method externally as a helper function then import it:

in a helper file:

```
async asynchronousFn() {
    const result = await (your asynchronous code)
    return result
}
```

in the component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    asynchronousfn().then(result => this.setState({ statekey: result }));
}
```

Comment: remember that async functions return a promise, and you don't want to stick a promise in state, you want to stick the result in state.

Comment: Hello, Ben hi is not really making the lifecycle method a async look this short post https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802 what I see here is that for future use your code is more clean

Answer (score 0):

With the callBack function on the [setState API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) you will fix your problem. In the link is the documentation of setState so you can see the setState and the arguments it accept.

I don't think you need a Async of Promise at this point as you see the [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) return a function, not a promise

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({user: user}, () => { this.props.retrieveMatches(this.state.user.uid); 
    })
   }
 });  
}
```